# How to make a function call after iframe content is fully loaded in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

As my question states I want to confirm/ make a function call once iframe content is fully loaded.

As I'm using Angular 8, I prefer typescript rather than using Js/jquery for a solution

This is what I have

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<iframe #iframe [src]="safeUrl"  style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>
```

TS

```
  export class AppComponent  {
  url:string='http://..';
  safeUrl:SafeResourceUrl;
  @ViewChild('iframe', {static:true}) iframe:ElementRef;

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){ 
    
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.safeUrl=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try implement AfterViewInit?

Comment: Yes,AfterViewInit makes function call even before the iframe completes loading

Answer (score 1):

Using load event

```
<iframe (load)="myLoadEvent()" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

In component

```
myLoadEvent(){
// do your task
}
```

Using Renderer2

```
<iframe #iframe id="iframe" name="pdfPreview" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
this._rndr.listen(this.iframeRef.nativeElement, 'load', (e) => { alert("works"); }
```

Adding callback to window

```
<iframe onload="loadEvent(event)" id="iframe" name="pdfPreview" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
(window as any).loadEvent = (event) => alert("works too");
```